# Почему вводное слово выделяется запятыми с двух сторон?

Tags: пунктуация

> Доктор, по-видимому, веселый и покладистый малый, рад был компании.

Вот здесь "веселый и покладистый малый" - это обособленное приложение. В таких обособленных конструкциях вводное слово выделяется только с одной стороны. Почему мы выделили его с двух?

Comment: Интересный вопрос, обратите, пожалуйста,  внимание. И  опять разные темы пересекаются в нем...

Answer (score 1):

В данном  случае вводное слово находится в начале обособленного оборота и не  отделяется  от него никаким знаком препинания.

Доктор, **по-видимому веселый и покладистый малый,** рад был компании.

Ср.: А Пётр Петрович, **по крайней мере по многим признакам,** человек весьма почтенный (Дост.); Все те, **небольшие конечно,** удовольствия, которые доставляла ей мать, она принимала с благодарностью (Леск.);

[См.: Д.Э. Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация.п.4.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146681/discussion-on-answer-by---------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.